# Why does my jquery code glitch for animation?

Tags: php, jquery, html

thanks for reading this,
I'm making a website. I have a popup box that asks if you are 18 years or older. Once you click "yes", the forum I'm making appears. When you click the reply button, for some unknown reason, the popup box reappears.
Why is that?

this is the php file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html 
     PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<title>Umich Chan</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
<script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.1/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js">
</script>


</head>
<body>

<div id="confirmage">
    <h2 style="text-align:center;">Are you older than 18 years old?</h2>
      <button id="close" style="display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;margin-bottom:5px;">Yes</button>
      <button id="linknoclose" style="display:block;margin:auto;">No</button>
</div>

<div id="fadeina" style="opacity:0;">
<p>
</p>

<a href="addpost.html">Post Anonymously Now</a><br>

<br>


<?php 

// Connect to server and select database.
$con = mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password", "$db_name") or die ("cannot connect"); 

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Table_forum ORDER BY `key` DESC");// 

// Start looping table row

while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$key=$rows['key'];
$name=$rows['name'];
$input=$rows['input'];

echo "<div class='answerbox'>";
echo '<font color="blue">' .$name. '</font>';
echo "<br />";
echo "$input.";
echo "<a class='reply' href=''>Reply</a>";
echo "</div>";
echo "<div class='replybox'><textarea></textarea></div>";

/*
echo "<div class='commentbox'>";
$namecomment = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT namea FROM `postcomments` WHERE keya = '1'");//
echo ".$name.";
$inputcomment = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT input FROM `postcomments` WHERE keya = '" .mysql_real_escape_string .$key."'");//
echo ".$inputcomment.";
echo "</div>";
*/
}
mysql_close();
?>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This the js file.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".replybox").hide();
    $(".reply").css("color","blue");

    $("#fadeina").hide();

    $(".reply").click(function(){
        $(".replybox").show();
    });

    $("#close").click(function(){
        $("#confirmage").remove();
    });

    $("#close").click(function(){
        $("#confirmage").empty();
    });

    $("#close").click(function(){
        $("#fadeina").fadeTo('slow',1);
    });

    $("#linknoclose").click(function(){
        history.back();
        return false; 
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you make SO Snippet for that?

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: It's seventh icon from left in question/answer box (box with pencil) or just CTRL + M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The popup box reappears because your `Reply` link has an empty `href`:

`"<a class='reply' href=''>Reply</a>";`

> As Stated in RFC 2396: A URI reference that does not contain a URI is
>   a reference to the current document. In other words, an empty URI
>   reference within a document is interpreted as a reference to the start
>   of that document

try using `href="javascript:;"`.

Comment: Thanks Jonny. Appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the `<button>` elements, the "reply" anchor needs `e.preventDefault()` (or `return false`) to inhibit its natural hyperlink behaviour, which will cause the page to reload.

The code will also simplify quite significantly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".replybox, #fadeina").hide();

    $(".reply").css("color","blue").on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); //<<<<<<<<
        $(".replybox").show();
    });

    $("#close").on('click', function() {
        $("#confirmage").remove();
        $("#fadeina").fadeTo('slow', 1);
    });

    $("#linknoclose").on('click', function() {
        history.back();
    });
});
```